# Interpreting BEA weblogic thread dumps - helpful documents and/or tools?

Tags: multithreading, weblogic, thread-dump

I am a neophyte at Weblogic troubleshooting.

We have an issue on our production environment. I cannot access the ennvironment directly (our hosting people will do that, but it's some hours until I can ask them things).

I have a thread dump from the time the issue was evident on production. I can look through the dump and deduce some things, but given it's quite structured and something people do all the time I'm assuming there are tools out there to help interpret them. Are there?

Failing that, are there some useful documents or websites that would help me learn to interpret them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:

[This is a neat tool](https://tda.dev.java.net/) for summarising the thread dumps.

[This](http://thread.dumps.googlepages.com/java-thread-dumps) and [this](http://thread.dumps.googlepages.com/java-thread-dumps-2) form a two-part article on interpreting thread dumps.

I still haven't found our issue, though, so still looking for more.